# JQuery switch between divs on click

Tags: jquery

I have the following setup:

```js
$(".form-wrapper .section").first().addClass('open').show();
$(".form-wrapper .section.open .sub-section:first-child").addClass('open').show();
var subtotal = 1;
$('.next-sub').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var subcount = $('.form-wrapper .section.open').data('subcount');

  if (subtotal === subcount) {
    $('.form-wrapper .section.open').addClass('close').next('.section').addClass('open').show();
    $('.form-wrapper .section.close').removeClass('open close').hide();
    $('.form-wrapper .section.open .sub-section:first-child').addClass('open').show();
    subtotal = 1;
    subcount = $('.form-wrapper .section.open').data('subcount');
  } else {
    var subcount = $('.form-wrapper .section.open').data('subcount');
    $('.form-wrapper .section.open .sub-section.open').addClass('close').next('.sub-section').addClass('open').show();
    $('.form-wrapper .section.open .sub-section.close').removeClass('open close').hide();
  }
  subtotal = subtotal + 1;
});
```

```css
.section,
.sub-section {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-wrapper">
  <div class="section" data-subcount="3">
    <div class="sub-section">1</div>
    <div class="sub-section">2</div>
    <div class="sub-section">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" data-subcount="4">
    <div class="sub-section">1</div>
    <div class="sub-section">2</div>
    <div class="sub-section">3</div>
    <div class="sub-section">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" data-subcount="2">
    <div class="sub-section">1</div>
    <div class="sub-section">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="next-sub" href="#">next</a>
```

My intended goal is you switch between the sub sections in each section, once you hit the last page in the current section it moves you til the next one, this works but the 2nd section will only go to the count for the first section, how do I solve this?

A JSFiddle is also available: https://jsfiddle.net/9p8cyLek/

Comment: You should reset your subtotal = 0 and not subtotal = 1, because you count +1 every time. So after reset the subtotal would already be 2.

Comment: Thanks Wiman, that solved it, so simple, thankd for the quick answer.

Comment: No problem. If found it so quickly because I did a console.log of both variables (subcount and subtotal). After debugging that you can catch it quickly. So important tip: always use console.log to see what your code is doing!

Comment: General observation. There is no reason to keep a `data-subcount` attribute. If you need to know how many subsections there are in any given section, count them. `$('someSection').children('.subSection').length` does not require much more typing than `$('someSection').data('subcount')`, but it has the advantage that it can never get out of sync with reality.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the element in the current section has any [next sibling](https://api.jquery.com/next/), to toggle the `sub-section`, or else, jump to the next `section`:

```js
$(".form-wrapper .section").first().addClass('open').show();
$(".form-wrapper .section.open .sub-section:first-child").addClass('open').show();

$('.next-sub').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Get current section and subsection
  $section = $(".form-wrapper .section.open");
  $subsection = $section.find(".sub-section.open");
  // It there is a next subsection, change to it
  $next = $subsection.next(".sub-section")
  if ($next.length) {
    $subsection.removeClass('open');
    $next.addClass('open');
  } else {
    // End of section, find next and set it and first subsection as active
    $subsection.removeClass('open')
    $section.removeClass('open');
    $nextSection = $section.next('.form-wrapper .section').addClass('open')
      .find('.sub-section:first-child').addClass('open')
  }
});
```

```css
.section,
.sub-section {
  display: none;
}

.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <div class="section" data-subcount="3">
    <div class="sub-section">1</div>
    <div class="sub-section">2</div>
    <div class="sub-section">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" data-subcount="4">
    <div class="sub-section">1</div>
    <div class="sub-section">2</div>
    <div class="sub-section">3</div>
    <div class="sub-section">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" data-subcount="2">
    <div class="sub-section">1</div>
    <div class="sub-section">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="next-sub" href="#">next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The effect can be achieved with a lot less code than you have:

```js
var $sections = $(".form-wrapper .section"),
    firstSection = $sections[0];

$(firstSection).addClass('open');

$('.next-sub').on('click', function() {
  var nextSection = $sections.filter('.open').removeClass('open').next('.section')[0];

  $(nextSection || firstSection).addClass('open');
});
```

```css
.section {
  display: none;
}
.section.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-wrapper">
  <div class="section" data-subcount="3">
    <div class="sub-section">1</div>
    <div class="sub-section">2</div>
    <div class="sub-section">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" data-subcount="4">
    <div class="sub-section">1</div>
    <div class="sub-section">2</div>
    <div class="sub-section">3</div>
    <div class="sub-section">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" data-subcount="2">
    <div class="sub-section">1</div>
    <div class="sub-section">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="next-sub" href="#">next</a>
```

It could even be a one-liner if need be (but I find this harder to read than the two-liner):

```
$('.next-sub').on('click', function() {
  $($sections.filter('.open').removeClass('open').next('.section')[0] || firstSection).addClass('open');
});
```